# How to get metamask address with infura?

Tags: metamask, addresses, infura

I am very new to the blockchain programming. I installed the `metamask` browser extension on my google chrome. I funded it everyday through Alchemy. Now I am working on a Laravel project which involves token manipulations ( withdrawing, ...), and I want to get the metamask account address through `infura`. How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether you work in Javascript or Python.
You can use web3.py library and in this link you can find for example how to check your wallet balance via web3.py library:

https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html?highlight=address%20amount#checking-the-balance-of-an-account

Here is a also a YTB which teaches you perfectly how to use the web3.py library.
https://youtu.be/M576WGiDBdQ

Comment: I am working with Laravel

Comment: You will be better of working with either Brownie (Python based) or Hardhat (Javascript based) as there is much more learning material for it.